# Error stopping function after alert message is shown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm developing a proxy service and everything works great. When you press the submit button, it has an onclick function. I also now have it detecting when adblock is enabled, and I don't want the funcion to go through if adblock is detected, (meaning I want it so the proxy won't actually start if you have adblock enabled, and I want the alert message  to pop up ONLY when you press the button UNTIL you disable adblock.)

If you have adblock, here's an example of what I'm looking for. (http://fastp.org/) On this website, if you have adblock enabled, you can't submit the form. Mine still goes through after you press "ok" on the alert box. In my javascript code I tried doing a "return false;" and also a "else" but nothing seems to work. I don't want the form to submit if you have adblock enabled.

I want it so if adblock is enabled, it will show the alert box, and when you press "ok" I don't want it to still launch the proxy in the new tab. I want it to launch when adblock is disabled.

Here's my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#browsebtn').click(function() {
    val = $('#urlinput').val();
    $('#urlinput').val(val.replace($('#remove1').val(), ""));
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#browsebtn').click(function() {
    val = $('#urlinput').val();
    $('#urlinput').val(val.replace($('#remove2').val(), ""));
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#browsebtn').click(function() {
    val = $('#urlinput').val();
    $('#urlinput').val(val.replace($('#remove3').val(), ""));
  });
});

function forceLower(strInput) {
  strInput.value = strInput.value.toLowerCase();
}

function checkAdBlocker() {
  try {
    fetch(
      new Request("https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js", {
        method: 'HEAD',
        mode: 'no-cors'
      })).catch(error => {
      showNotification();
    });
  } catch (e) {
    // Request failed, likely due to ad blocker
    showNotification();
  }
  var x;
  x = document.getElementById("urlinput").value;
  if (x == "" || x == "https://" || x == "http://" || x == "www." || x == "http://www." || x == "https://www.") {
    $("#error").show().delay(3000).fadeOut();
    return false;
  } else {
    var ddl = document.getElementById("servertype");
    var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
    if (selectedValue == "server1") {
      setTimeout(function() {
        window.open('http://server1.com/' + document.getElementById('urlinput').value);
      }, 200);
    }
    if (selectedValue == "server2") {
      setTimeout(function() {    
    window.open('http://server2.com/' + document.getElementById('urlinput').value);
      }, 200);

    }
    if (selectedValue == "server3") {
      setTimeout(function() {
        window.open('http://server3.com/' + document.getElementById('urlinput').value);
      }, 200);

    }
    if (selectedValue == "server4") {
      setTimeout(function() {
        window.open('http://server4.com/' + document.getElementById('urlinput').value);
      }, 200);

    }
  }
}

function showNotification() {
  alert("Please disable adBlocker");
}
```

```html
<form action="javascript:void(0);" method="POST">
  <input id="remove1" type="hidden" value="https://" /><input id="remove2" type="hidden" value="http://" /><input id="remove3" type="hidden" value="www." />

  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter web address.." id="urlinput" onkeyup="return forceLower(this);" /><button type="submit" id="browsebtn" onclick="return checkAdBlocker()" name="submit" value="Browse">BROWSE</button>

  <div class="serverselect"><label>Select Server:</label></div>

  <div class="selectserver">
    <select id="servertype" name="dropdown">
      <option value="server1" data-sort="1"> US Server</option>
      <option value="server2" data-sort="2"> CA Server</option>
      <option value="server3" data-sort="3"> DE Server</option>
      <option value="server4" data-sort="4"> GB Server</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <p id="error">Please enter a valid URL address.</p>
</form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Sorry, yes I know the code is long, but I wanted to make sure the new code wouldn't affect any code that was left out. (everything is sort of looped together) Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In similar cases I usually use `try...catch` in `while loop` as track it with  variable:

```
while (true) {
    var adBlocker = false
    try {
        fetch(
            new Request("https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js", {
                method: 'HEAD',
                mode: 'no-cors'
            })).catch(error => {
                showNotification();
                adBlocker = true
            });
    } catch (e) {
        // Request failed, likely due to ad blocker
        showNotification();
        adBlocker = true
    }
    if (adBlocker == false) {
        break
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
`fetch` is async function so `adBlocker` variable is `false` and the loop is broken before cathing error
In this code I made fetch In async function to be able to use `await` and call `redirect` from `then` method that works on `fetch` success:

```
function checkAdBlocker() {
async function AdBlock() {
    try {
        // Wait for fetch
        let adTest = await fetch("https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js")
            .then(response => {
                redirect()
                adBlocker = false;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                showNotification();
            });
    } catch (e) {
        // Request failed, likely due to ad blocker
        showNotification();
    }
}

AdBlock()


function redirect() {
    var x;
    x = document.getElementById("urlinput").value;
    if (x == "" || x == "https://" || x == "http://" || x == "www." || x == "http://www." || x == "https://www.") {
        $("#error").show().delay(3000).fadeOut();
        return false;
    } else {
        var ddl = document.getElementById("servertype");
        var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
        if (selectedValue == "server1") {
            setTimeout(function () {
                window.open('https://devoooo-proxy.herokuapp.com/proxy/' + document.getElementById('urlinput').value);
            }, 200);
        }
        if (selectedValue == "server2") {
            setTimeout(function () {
                window.open('https://google-github.herokuapp.com/http/' + document.getElementById('urlinput').value);
            }, 200);

        }
        if (selectedValue == "server3") {
            setTimeout(function () {
                window.open('https://proxy.bibliotecavirtualalergia.com/browse.php?u=http://' + document.getElementById('urlinput').value);
            }, 200);

        }
        if (selectedValue == "server4") {
            setTimeout(function () {
                window.open('http://server3main.epizy.com/browse.php?u=http://' + document.getElementById('urlinput').value);
            }, 200);

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It works, but it still doesn't get rid of the opening of the new tab. I want it so the new tab won't open after the alert box is shown.

Comment: Ok the problem is that `fetch` is asynchronous function so the code don't wait for its response I have updated the answer try it (:

Comment: Hi, thanks for putting so much time into this. So far it seems like it's working but whenever you try to close out of the alert box, it opens back up again - it never stops. If you have an adblocker, please try to look at this error https://codepen.io/Ri12345/pen/KKWoqmy

Comment: Simply delete `while loop` (: